# Drafts widget for admin page

Tags: widgets, wp-admin, draft

The Quick Draft widget on the admin dashboard has an area to create a new post and a list of recent drafts.  I'd like a widget like this but with ONLY a list of recent drafts.  Surprisingly, I couldn't find a plugin that already does this.  What's my best way forward - can I modify the Quick Drafts widget, or clone it?

Answer (score 0):

if you are comfortable with it maybe you can make the widget yourself?  It would be a very easy plugin to make, just one query with a about three parameters.

Comment: Just not sure where to start.

Comment: just run a query that gets all the posts you want to list and display them in the widget you make using the code at this link:
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-widget/

Comment: I guess it worked out? Your welcome!